# Unknown command “script” (type /help for help) in WeeChat

Tags: linux, debian, irc, weechat

I've been trying to load some python scripts into WeeChat but every time I use the command `/script load script.py` it returns the line 'unknown command “script” (type /help for help)'.

Anyone know how I can get around this?